# search my google drive for all documents that have been shared with a link privately or are open on the web

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-search

Is it possible to search for all google drive documents that have been shared with a link privately or are open on the web ?

In the advance search you can search for files shares with particular people, but i would like to run a report on files shared either with a link privately or are open on the web.

Comment: Send feedback to Google while in Drive. I just did it in desktop and it send a screenshot and gave a checkbox to allow an email reply. This seems like a crucial feature to have (especially considering how poorly I see admins manage files, and the liabilities they create).

Answer (score 4):

It seems Drive URL query parameters doesn't support such searching now(It was probably removed in 2009). The only way you can search by those parameters now is probably by google-apps-script or DRIVE REST API.

---

- [Official search](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375114) parameters support only `to:`email parameter. So,If you know the email address,You can easily filter out the files.

---

- [GOOGLE-APPS-SCRIPT](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchFiles(String))

  ```
  function driveSearch() {
    // Log the name of every file in the user's Drive whose visibility is anyonewithLink or anyonecanfind
    var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(
      'visibility = "anyoneWithLink" or visibility = "anyoneCanFind"');
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      //var owner = file.getOwner().getName();
      //var sa = file.getSharingAccess();
      Logger.log(file.getName());
      //Logger.log('Owner:'+owner);
      //Logger.log("SharingAccess:"+sa);
    }
    }
  ```

---

- [DRIVE REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters)

Sample Python Code from the official documentation

```
    page_token = None
    while True:
    response = drive_service.files().list(q="mimeType='image/jpeg'",
                                      spaces='drive',
                                      fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
                                      pageToken=page_token).execute()
    for file in response.get('files', []):
    # Process change
    print 'Found file: %s (%s)' % (file.get('name'), file.get('id'))
    page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
    if page_token is None:
    break
```

Comment: This Google Apps scripts is great and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Go here https://script.google.com/home to create an app script (it's not immediately obvious). Create a new script, copy paste this, and forth you roll. I couldn't solve my initial problem (tons of "link shared" files owned by other people invading my drive), but this answer worked well with a few tweaks, e.g. if "owner = me" for tidying up stuff I was accidentally or obsoletely sharing.

Comment: I wonder why Google would have removed the ability to filter by visibility:all.

Answer (score 1):

The [official help article](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375114?hl=en) about search on Google Drive doesn't describe how to search for files shared by usingn a link.

For consumer accounts (usually accounts from gmail.com) the alternative is to use a script, an addon or a third-party app. If you have a G Suite account, on the advanced search options, on location you could select the option "Visible to all users on ". For further details see [Find Drive documents in your domain](https://support.google.com/a/answer/3187967?hl=en).

If you are G Suite admin, you could use the [Security reports](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6000269) to find files shared with a link.

Comment: Thanks I was looking at the old search box in google drive and it allowed you to actually filter a search by sharing settings (see here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/whXV1.gif). Do you know if its possible to recreate this functionality inside of the search bar by using a search string something like `visibility: not shared` ? I dont really want to run a 3rd party addon that will have access to my account, but could run a script do you know of one, ive searched by couldn't find one that audited my whole drive